# Weight painted, but mesh won't move along with Armature

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, pose-mode

I have only ever used the option to parent with automatic weights and then simply painted the neck for the wearable, but this time that didn't work. So I manually did some weight painting, but the mesh won't move at all when in pose mode. I am also very very new to this so I have absolutely no clue what could've gone wrong.

Let me know if you need the link to the file to take a better look at it.

Thanks in advance for helping out!

Link to download the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PcmUFIxb2ng5YvfKcGmG7qqcuI5KJjy9/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

@moonboots When I try to merge by distance the model starts to look weird in terms of how its shadows and highlights:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add the link to it into your question.

Comment: The weights you did make no sense to me. You painted the whole arm except the articulations, if it ever had to work that would mean that one bone would move all your arm's mesh except the articulations.

Comment: Can you precise in which way automatic weights didn't work? Did you get an error, perhaps (which one)? Even if you wanted to make your weights manually, it would be nice to start from an automatic generation first, because it still does the groundwork. Each bone needs its own vertex group with the bone name (I bet that's precisely what you missed here), it's really time-consuming to do that manually.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but in what mode did you move the bones? If you move the bones in Edit mode, the mesh won't deform, you need to be in Pose Mode.

Comment: Also, when you are in weight paint mode, you need to select a bone before painting so that the painted vertices are asigned to that bone. In your second screnshot, I don't see any bone selected.

Comment: @L0Lock I followed a bit of this tutorial where they deleted all vertex groups before parenting with automatic weights and since they did that I figured I should do that still even if not using automatic weights, but I guess then those should stay? The error that comes up says : "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"

Here's a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PcmUFIxb2ng5YvfKcGmG7qqcuI5KJjy9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I was in pose mode when moving the bones. I didn't select any bones before painting, so I will try that out, thank you!

Comment: Your link asks for an authorisation

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Selecting a bone first actually solved it! The mesh is now moving along :) Can't believe it was so simple haha.

Comment: @moonboots my bad, does it work now?

Comment: @moonboots When I "merge by distance" The model start to look a bit odd, I will include an image for you

Answer (score 1):

You have overlapping faces, select all in Edit mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, parent again *With Automatic Weights*